# PHP 5.2 and PHP 5.3 side-by-side in vHosts on the same Apache (Debian)?

Tags: php, apache2

Is there a chance to have various versions of PHP (right now I'd like to have 5.2 and 5.3 side by side) running on the same machine just within different vHosts? I'm running a Debian server and the PHP packages come from dotdeb.org - is there a easy way to achieve such a setup? Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524508/how-can-one-run-multiple-versions-of-php-5-x-on-a-development-lamp-server

Answer (score 1):

Install to differing module names such as

```
mod_php52
mod_php53
```

Don't forget to specify differing config directories if you build using ./configure

In vhost 1

```
LoadModule mod_php52 modules/mod_php52.so
```

In vhost 2

```
LoadModule mod_php53 modules/mod_php53.so
```

**Warning** I have not tried this, and there will likely be all sorts of library problems, so be careful that both modules don't try and use the same libs. Build into distinct directories as many of the dependencies as you can. It could get tricky!

Comment: hm ok thanks for the answer - I'm using Debian because I don't like to compile anything (especially not PHP ;) ) and I like that it resolves all the dependencies during the installation of a package ... it think since it's actually a coLinux environment (with Debian Distro) I'll just create another coLinux service an my Dev-Machine instead of blowing up my old (stable) setup... I thought there's an easy way but it seems that I run into tons of issues (especially library issues) when I make the attempt to install 5.3 ...