# Php7 and php5 on fedora at the same time

Tags: php, linux, apache, nginx, fedora

How can I setup PHP5 and PHP7 on one Fedora system?

As I see, PHP in fedora is not one directory, it's spread in OS.

On Windows systems, PHP is one folder, so I can just rename it when I need a specific version of PHP. What about Fedora?

Maybe there are some useful links but I haven't found them.

Also, it will be `php5+apache(httpd)` and `php7+nginx`, but I don't think it matters for now.

Comment: Typically when you want to maintain two separate php versions on a single system you do that in one of two ways: 1. you use one version as http server module, the other one as cgi or fastcgi application. That way you can use the standard paths. Or you pack each version in a separate folder, craft individual configuration files (adapting the paths) and switch between versions by simply specifying the configuration files location on CLI or inside the http server configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one run multiple versions of PHP 5.x on a development LAMP server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524508/how-can-one-run-multiple-versions-of-php-5-x-on-a-development-lamp-server)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you to install remi repository. I assume you use fedora 23.

`sudo dnf install  http://rpms.remirepo.net/fedora/remi-release-23.rpm`

After installing remi repository, you have to edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo` file and enable it.
Finally you can install various versions of php. for example:

`sudo dnf install php70-php php56-php`

You can use them as `php70`  and `php56` along with option or php file you want to run.

Comment: You can install both php70-php php56-php (which is mod_php) but only once, will work. Better to use php70-php-fpm and  php56-php-fpm, as you can run 2 services, 1 per version.

Comment: i installed mine without the version number, like `install php` and it was the version 7 that popped up

Comment: I have F29 and I installed the repo but it does not have the links for php56 only php73

Comment: @ateebahmed Did you see http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/ just like remi-collet mentioned?

Comment: yes, I followed till I install the repo after that since it does not have urls for 5 it gives 404, already checked elsewhere about this and it seems they don't support 5 now, thanks anyway I am using laravel right now, needed it for CI. Hope that doesn't break anywhere

Answer (score 6):

Following directions in Remi RPM repo blog worked for me. I can now run php55 or php70.
https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2016/04/16/My-PHP-Workstation

Few things that it took to switch to php55:

```
 module unload php70
 module load php55

 yum install php55-php-fpm

 systemctl start php55-php-fpm
 systemctl enable php55-php-fpm
```

now both `php --version` in command line shows PHP 5.5 and also in your browser you will see that phpinfo() shows PHP 5.5.

Comment: This answer is very helpful in addition to the selected answer and I actually use the details in here as well, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can install as many versions as PHP as you want.  Just download the source code and compile whichever version you want into separate directories.

```
./configure --prefix='/usr/local/php-7.0.4'
make
make install
```

Using fpm, you can set up different sockets or TCP ports for each version of PHP which can be used inside your web server config (nginx fastcgi or something like mod_fastcgi for apache)

Answer (score 1):

Yes Software Collections is the current best solution for parallel installations of various PHP versions.

As SCL are not yet allowed in Fedora official repository, you have to use the "remi" repository.

See the Configuration Wizard on http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Also see

- http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/03/25/PHP-7.0-as-Software-Collection
- http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2014/03/28/PHP-FPM-and-HTTPD-2.4-improvement