# Is it possible to switch versions for things like PHP in my dev sandbox without reinstalling?

Tags: php, ubuntu

I'm working on a dev sandbox which will mostly be used for integration testing.

I'd like to be able to run legacy versions of things like the magento cart platform which are compatible with older versions of php and so on.

I'd really like to be able to concurrently install several versions of PHP and then call them at the top of the file so it knows which version to evaluate scripts with, but I have no idea where to start configuring something like that.

Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one run multiple versions of PHP 5.x on a development LAMP server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524508/how-can-one-run-multiple-versions-of-php-5-x-on-a-development-lamp-server)

Comment: Hmm partially but I would like to ideally run 4, 5, 6 and 7 so that I can handle a whole suite of legacy software.

Answer (score 1):

It may be beneficial to use a Virtual Machine set up of some kind such as Vagrant. Or perhaps run separate containers in Docker.

For something like vagrant I would build off another Vagrant box. Scotch.io have a really quick box you can use: https://box.scotch.io/
The docs for vagrant can be found here:
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/

I have seen a lot of developers use Docker to run older versions of software for projects.

I would suggest reading the documentation for Docker here: 
https://docs.docker.com/

Both Vagrant and Docker are larger subjects that I can explain in this answer.

If you want some more reading I found this on stackoverflow
[Should I use Vagrant or Docker for creating an isolated environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647069/should-i-use-vagrant-or-docker-for-creating-an-isolated-environment)
It may help with deciding between docker and Vagrant.

I hope this helps in some way.

Comment: Some great tips. I'm going to give Docker a try and I'll accept your answer once I do! Thanks.