# Run php5 and php7 in parrallel

Tags: php, apache

I have php5 and php7 applications.

The php5 application are not compatible with php7.

How can I run both runtime on the same apache server ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php .

Comment: We don't have time and budget for migration, not my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your operating system is ubuntu, then you can set up multiple instances of Apache, one to run PHP 5 and the other to run PHP 6 according to this [article](https://gist.github.com/aaronbloomfield/92c707631a0191152bc7faf0124fd651).

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you need to use fastcgi.

You should look here for doing so:http://linuxplayer.org/2011/05/intall-multiple-version-of-php-on-one-server

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to but you'll need access to the server, so shared web hosting is probably off limits. Have a look at this answer from another SO post. I believe that should apply here.

> One way to do this is to have your main version of php set up with
>   mod_php and run all of the others through fast cgi on different ports
>   (i.e. 81, 82, 83 etc). This won't guarantee totally consistent
>   behavior though.

[*Credit to Dana the Sane*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/524532/7236046)

**So one version is done through CGI and the other is done as an apache module.**

Alternatively you could look into upgrading your php5 code to be compatible for php7 as it'll make it more stable and secure. *Albeit time consuming though.*

Comment: Here is a pretty detailed old-school way of doing it: http://gggeek.altervista.org/2007/07/21/running-multiple-php-versions-on-a-single-apache-install/