# how to check if there are multiple versions of php in windows10 need 7.1 for laravel packages?

Tags: php, laravel, php-7

I have downloaded two versions of PHP 5.6.35 and 7.1
set there environment variables but each time i run command to check versions

```
php -v
```

it gives 5.6

I need 7.0 for laravel packages but my wamp server requires 5.6.

i set the path variable of both .
but when i use in project it give's eror

```
doctrine/inflector v1.2.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement
```

any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one run multiple versions of PHP 5.x on a development LAMP server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524508/how-can-one-run-multiple-versions-of-php-5-x-on-a-development-lamp-server)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one run multiple versions of PHP 5.x on a development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524508/how-can-one-run-multiple-versions-of-php-5-x-on-a-development-lamp-server)

Comment: i don't require this in server

Comment: where do u need it?

Comment: in  laravel packages they require >= 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get 5.6, because it set in your `PATH` system variable.
If you need an additional 7.0, you could download it and use full path to php.exe to execute it.

Example:

```
C:\php7\php.exe -v
```

Or you could change `PATH` to php 7 directory. Then you will be able to run it with only `php` command. In this case, to run php 5.6 you will have to use full path to it. Don't forget to logout/reboot the system to apply the `PATH` variable changes.

Set only one version of php to `PATH` because system runs the first founded php.exe, in your case this is php 5.6.

Comment: i set the path as well but i run in my project i give error    doctrine/inflector v1.2.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: You could use it from any dir, using a full path to php executable. `C:\php7\php.exe` instead of just `php`

Comment: yes i set full path "C:\php7\php.exe" but not work's outside dir

Comment: You need to logout/reboot the system to apply changes to PATH variable.

Comment: same after reboot

Comment: In your latest question edit i saw you set both php dirs to PATH. It's not a good idea, because system runs the first founded php.exe, in your case this is php 5.6. You should set only one version of php to PATH, that you want to execute with only `php`. For other one you should use full path, and don't add it to PATH.

Comment: yes you are right i set both php dirs to path and 5.6 comes first ok i set it to one

Answer (score 1):

You can install multiple versions of php in Windows. But you need to do the following every time you need a run a project which supports a specific PHP version:

- Enable php module for Apache/Nginx etc.
- Add php executable path to global PATH variable, and remove references to old path.

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597067/how-to-run-php-from-windows-command-line/16289254#16289254) on how to automate version change on Windows.