# Apache - Multiple PHP by port on one virtual host

Tags: php, virtualhost, apache2

I have a little stupid problem but from the beginning:
I have a project for which I have created Virtual Host, which uses the default PHP plugged in under Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *: 80>
     DocumentRoot "C: \ web \ project"
     ServerName project.dev
     <Directory "C: \ web \ project">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     </ Directory>
</ VirtualHost>
```

Now I would need to run exactly the same project on a different version of PHP (preferably through the port) under the same Apache without having to create new Virtual Hosts under each Apache with a different version of PHP, e.g.

```
http://project.dev -> Default PHP Apache 

http://project.dev:8056 -> PHP 5.6 

http://project.dev:8071 -> PHP 7.1
```

etc.

Is it possible to achieve? (Not necessarily under Windows but under such "home" linux)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible in a number of ways: using [php-fpm](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM) or the `AddHandler` directive.

In Linux you would install a base version and then compile other versions. There's a complete solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524508/how-can-one-run-multiple-versions-of-php-5-x-on-a-development-lamp-server

Answer (score -1):

```
<VirtualHost *: 80>
     DocumentRoot "C: \ web \ project"
     ServerName project.dev
     <Directory "C: \ web \ project">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     </ Directory>
</ VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *: 81>
     DocumentRoot "C: \ web \ project"
     ServerName project.dev
     <Directory "C: \ web \ project">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     </ Directory>
</ VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *: 82>
     DocumentRoot "C: \ web \ project"
     ServerName project.dev
     <Directory "C: \ web \ project">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     </ Directory>
</ VirtualHost>
```

Change the directory.. you can add multiple virtual host in same file
Add the port number in ports.conf file

Restart your server it will work

Comment: Three times the same config. parameters. No information which should use PHP64 and which PHP32, different architecture or different versions .